# Firebreath won't compile using Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, firebreath, log4cplus

I'm trying to build the OSX Firebreath plugin. It builds just fine if I set the target OS to 10.8, but if I try to move it back to 10.6, I get the following error message:

```
/Users/dwiedeback/Github/plugin-dev/
   firebreath/src/libs/log4cplus/include/
   log4cplus/internal/internal.h:142:8: 

   error: thread-local storage is unsupported for the current target
```

Not sure why thread-local storage isn't supported for 10.6. Has anyone run into this with Firebreath?

Comment: What version of log4cplus is Firebreath using?

Comment: OK, it looks like it is version 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably avoid this issue if you manage **not** to have `LOG4CPLUS_HAVE_TLS_SUPPORT` defined in log4cplus' `defines.hxx`. Then the log4cplus source will not try to use the `__thread` keyword and will use POSIX thread-local storage facilities instead.

However, the best of all options would be to debug and find out why is the TLS check in [`ConfigureChecks.cmake`](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/libs/log4cplus/ConfigureChecks.cmake) giving a false positive.